# Refactoring Java Code: Eliminating or Streamlining a Boolean Variable Outside a For Loop

Tags: java, refactoring

I am struggling with the following problem in my code:

```
boolean target = false;
for (Item item : list) {
  if (item.boolA || target == true) {
    if (item.boolB) {
      target = false;
    } else if (item.boolC) {
      target = true;
    } else {
      target = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to eliminate or refactor the 'target' variable outside the for loop, possibly by moving it into a method to make the code more concise. Am I stuck on a problem that has no solution?

I finally tried asking ChatGPT for assistance, but it didn't yield the results I was expecting.

Comment: You might want to "refactor" the `bool[A/B/C]` first.

Comment: Provide some more information about the abstraction.  What are the values, and how do they pertain to the execution of this function?  Paraphrasing might impede this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to know whether a list of items satisfies a certain condition, and perhaps base what you would do next based on the outcome. I don't know how your list is being created, but if it is possible, you could have your own class that represents a list of items, for instance `ItemsList`. This could be a wrapper for a `List<Item>` with constraints on the kind and the distribution of `Item`s that you could append. One possibility is to have a method inside the `ItemsList` that does what you would like to do when the condition you want to check for isn't satisfied, and then create a sub-class that corresponds to a list of items that satisfies the same condition and override the method in question by doing what you would like to do when the condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

This refactoring, which is equivalent to your code, achieves the "more concise" goal:

```
boolean target = false;
for (Item item : list) {
    if (item.boolA || target) {
        target = !item.boolB && item.boolC;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: Fast Succeeding Method**

You can bail out of the loop once a `true` state is found:

```
    boolean target = fastSucceedTest(list);

    private boolean fastSucceedTest(List<Item> list) {
        for (Item item : list) {
            if (item.boolA && !item.boolB && item.boolC) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how bailing out of the loop works.  In the O/P code, suppose `target` , at some point, has been set to `true`, and the end of `list` has not been reached. So, `item` is set to the next element. Because `target`  is `true`, `item.boolB` is tested. If that is `true`, then `target` is cleared to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2: Stream filtering**

Filter all the elements find only the ones matching the boolean expression, if you find any, then the target is `true`.

```
boolean target = list.stream()
     .filter(item -> item.boolA && !item.boolB && item.boolC)
     .count() > 0;
```